# Scrolling Stopped with MMDrawer iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, mmdrawercontroller

I'm using UIScrollView on my ViewController And Also used MMDrawerController

Implementation Is As:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * leftVC=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideDrawer"];
UIViewController * centerVC=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
UINavigationController * leftNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:leftVC];
UINavigationController * centerNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:centerVC];
self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                         initWithCenterViewController:centerNav
                         leftDrawerViewController:leftNav
                         rightDrawerViewController:nil];
CGFloat menuWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.8;
[self.drawerController setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:menuWidth];
[self.drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
[self.drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I implement UIScrollView on ViewController ,Some times scrollview stops and MMDrawer is open .  how to handle MMDrawer Open /Close with UIScrollView.
When I tring to scroll  the scrollview item Scrolling is stopped and menu is opened.
Any Help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution . In my code There was problem with my content size of UIScrollView Frame.